# How can I make sure that I can print 0 instead a negative number to refer as the enemy being dead in a fighting game

Tags: python

I'm a fairly new programmer, but I am trying to make a fighting game code, but I have been stumped on one part, within my code I am trying to make sure that when the enemy health = 0, it will end. I can make the program end, well. But I don't want to enemy health to go under 0, it can work with me fine, but I really want to change this.

```
import random
gameactive = 0
x= 100

while gameactive == 0:
    if x > 0:
        crit = random.randint(8,9)
        base = random.randint(5,6)
        a = random.randint(1,10)
        if a == 10:
            x -= crit
            print("\nITS A CRITICAL HIT!") # Dont mind this please, this chunk about critical hits.
            print("\n")
            print(str(x) + " Health left")
        else:
            x -= base
            print("\n")
            print(str(x) + " Health left")
    else:
        break
```

so what happens when the program is ran, it will generate numbers and decreases x using those generated numbers. But when running the program, I want the code to only limit itself 0 health and not go under.
Sorry if i horribly explained it simply put, I want a way so x will be capped at 0, and it will not print negative numbers and instead print some sample text like enemy died.

Comment: `x = max(x, 0)?`

Comment: where would I add this?

Comment: @justbeingnev Do `x = max(0, x - crit)` instead of `x -= crit`, and `x = max(0, x - base)` instead of `x -= base`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use max function like t his:

```
import random
gameactive = 0
x= 100

while gameactive == 0:
    if x > 0:
        crit = random.randint(8,9)
        base = random.randint(5,6)
        a = random.randint(1,10)
        if a == 10:
            x -= crit
            print("\nITS A CRITICAL HIT!") # Dont mind this please, this chunk about critical hits.
        else:
            x -= base
        print("\n")
        print(str(max(x,0)) + " Health left")

    else:
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to change where you print "x Health left". So in the code below, at each iteration the value of `x` will be reported *before* the hit, until x goes below zero, in which case the custom message "x died" or similar can be printed, and the loop breaks.

```
while gameactive == 0:
    
    if x > 0:
        #report current health here, before hit
        print(str(x) + " Health left")

        crit = random.randint(8,9)
        base = random.randint(5,6)
        a = random.randint(1,10)
        if a == 10:
            x -= crit
            print("\nITS A CRITICAL HIT!") # Dont mind this please, this chunk about critical hits.
            print("\n")
        else:
            x -= base
            print("\n")
    else:
        #x died
        print("x died.")
        break
```